# Why vector field can be the gradient of a function $f$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Because I always treat the gradient of $f$  ($\nabla f$ ) as $\nabla_ifdx^i$.And the vector field should be $X=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. So I am fuzzy with that why vector field can be the gradient of a function $f$.

The above question is on Riemanian manifold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On any manifold, you can compute the differential $df$ of a real-valued function $f$, and $df$ is a covector field, also called a differential one-form. (And it's written with the index downstairs when working in coordinates or in abstract index notation.)

On a Riemannian manifold, you can use the metric to raise the index on $df$, and the result of this is (by definition) the gradient vector field $\nabla f$. (And it's written with the index upstairs.)

Comment: (+1), but I think you can (and perhaps should) make the point more forcefully:  The primary distinction between the differential and gradient isn't merely notational, and the two are not interchangeable pieces of data. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Well, they are sort of interchangeable via the metric tensor, but yes, one is a covector field and the other one is a vector field, so of course they're different objects.

Comment: As I see it, the main point of your answer (and the central point of the OP's uncertainty) is that $df$ _depends only on the smooth structure of the manifold_, while the gradient depends on a choice of Riemannian metric. In that sense the differential and gradient are _not_ interchangeable; specifying a Riemannian metric is a genuine choice.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: I agree completely.

Comment: To be clear, though, not every vector field on a Riemannian manifold can be written as the gradient of some function.

Comment: @JesseMadnick: Absolutely, just like not every covector field is the differential of some function.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang   Great.